# Make - nothing to be done for all (another one)

Tags: c++, dll, makefile

Make says it has nothing to do for all. I have searche the internet and there are dozens of situations when it says this thing. None of the solutions helped though...

I use MinGW, in my directory I have `Res.def`, `Res.h`, `Res.cpp` and `Res.o` which I've got after running `g++ -c Res.cpp`.

Here is the makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -c -G3 -GX -Od -W3 -Zi -D_X86_=1 -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -nologo -DSTRICT
LFLAGS = -debug:mapped,full -debugtype:cv -nologo
LIBS = libc.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib 
SRCS = Res.def Res.cpp Res.h
OBJS = Res.o

all: Res.dll

Res.dll: $(SRCS) $(OBJS)


$(SRCS):
    co $(SRCS)

.cpp.obj:
    cl $(CFLAGS) $*.cpp
.rc.rbj:
    rc $*.rc
    cvtres -i386 $*.res -o $*.rbj
.obj.dll:
    link $(LFLAGS) -DLL -subsystem:windows -out:$*.dll \
        -def:$*.def $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
.obj.exe:
    link $(LFLAGS) -subsystem:console -out:$*.exe \
        $*.obj $(EXELIBS)
```

How do I make the dll?

**UPDATE:**

I come from Java and when i can make sense of C or C++, am a total noob at make files and hereby I am trying to re-assemble an open-source dll after doing some changes to the code. I have read about building C applications but it does not help much. The original make file had `OBJS` line different, it was

`OBJS = Res.obj`

I have changed it to `OBJS = Res.o` when trying to somehow manage to build the dll. So that the original file was:

```
CFLAGS = -c -G3 -GX -Od -W3 -Zi -D_X86_=1 -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -nologo -DSTRICT
LFLAGS = -debug:mapped,full -debugtype:cv -nologo
LIBS = libc.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib 
SRCS = Res.def Res.cpp Res.h
OBJS = Res.obj

all: Res.dll

Res.dll: $(SRCS) $(OBJS)


$(SRCS):
    co $(SRCS)

.cpp.obj:
    cl $(CFLAGS) $*.cpp
.rc.rbj:
    rc $*.rc
    cvtres -i386 $*.res -o $*.rbj
.obj.dll:
    link $(LFLAGS) -DLL -subsystem:windows -out:$*.dll \
        -def:$*.def $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
.obj.exe:
    link $(LFLAGS) -subsystem:console -out:$*.exe \
        $*.obj $(EXELIBS)
```

With that default line, it was saying another thing:

```
*** No rule to make target `Res.obj`, needed by `Res.dll`. Stop.
```

Please could you tell me how to assemble this simple dll? I am totally lost. These complexities seem to me an overkill for such a simple task of building a lib from a single source file....?

Comment: You don't seem to have a rule for `.o` files.

Comment: @KerrekSB: yeah, sorry, see the update

Comment: I don't see it. There's still no rule for `Res.o`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: heh , ok, I've updated the update )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have up-to-date `$(OBJS)` in your directory, and there is really nothing to be done for `all`.

Linking usually concerns more than one object file, so it's more conventional to specify linking rules for each binary explicitly:

```
Res.dll: $(OBJS) Res.def
      link ...
```

(note that Res.dll doesn't depend on .h and .cpp directly).

But of course you can specify a rule for building a .dll file from an .o file instead. I guess this is what you are trying to do, but your Makefile only has a rule for building a .dll file from an **.obj** file (not **.o**).

One more thing: the `Res.o` file should depend on Res.cpp and Res.h. So you need something like:

```
Res.o: Res.h

.cpp.o:
      g++ -c $<
```

Comment: Ehhh... Yeah, looks like.. and you are right about the obj file.. please see the update..

Comment: Which file do you have after compiling the .cpp, Res.o or Res.obj? This file should be specified in the .dll dependencies, and ALSO there must be a rule or a command on how to make the .dll from this object file. Rule `.obj.dll:` tells how to make .dll from .obj. If your file is `Res.o` you should replace `.obj.dll:` with `.o.dll:`. Or just specify the linking command at the line following 'Res.dll: ...' dependencies (and don't forget to make a TAB indent before the command).

Comment: If I manually run `g++ -shared Res.o`, I get an `a.exe` file created. But I suppose this is just a wrong-named dll. When I watch the binary content, I see all the functions there, but they're not accessible from outside since, I suppose, I did not use the `Res.def` file during creation. And it is 25kb against 125kb of the original dll, I guess coz `*.lib` files are not there. So, I try `make .o.dll` and it comes up with the error that it can't find `libc.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib`.. there are no such libs in my MinGW... and I can't find where to download them..

Comment: alright, I have found `libuser32.a` and `libkernel32.a` in the MinGW installation. I guess I have to use them. But no luck with finding a replacement for `libc.lib`.

Comment: The Makefile you are trying to adapt looks like it has been written for MS Visual Studio (there you would have 'LINK' command and all that libs). For MinGW, the appropriate link command is `gcc -o Res.dll -shared Res.o` (no need to specify libc, kernel32 and user32 libs). MinGW doesn't use .DEF files for exporting functions from DLLs; instead, you should declare the functions in sources (usually in a header file) with `__declspec(dllexport)` specifier like `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall MyPublicFunction(int, int);`. In fact, MinGW differs from MS Visual Studio in many points.