# mingw32-make.exe: Nothing to be done for 'all'

Tags: c++, makefile, target

When I tried to run a cpp project, I met run-time errors.

the following message is shown in the Compilation Log:

```
mingw32-make.exe -f "D:\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\Makefile.win" all
mingw32-make.exe: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Within the Makefile, I found:

```
.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after
```

But I don't understand what exactly the error is and what's the function of "all"

Comment: Is that your entire makefile? What it *supposed* to do?.. Because clearly it does nothing, which make informs you about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make - nothing to be done for all (another one)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993244/make-nothing-to-be-done-for-all-another-one)

Answer (score 3):

That is not an error message.

Basically it tells you that the `all` target (and, by implication, all its dependencies -- `all-before`, `all-after` and whatever it is that is in `BIN`) **is** already up to date, i.e. there is no need for `make` to run any commands.